# German Umlaut displayed wrong despite correct Charset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, utf-8, asp-classic, character-encoding, codepages

I am encountering a weird problem regarding the encoding of my files.
                I have a site which is multilingual; Users can set this viá a dropdown on the site itself, the default value being German.
                When the user logs in, some settings are being set depending on the language (charset, codepage and LCID). At this point I also want to point out, that all my files are ANSI-encoded.
                Recently, I had to make some changes. 
                So I fire up `Visual Studio 2010`, edit the files in question and upload them to my server using Filezilla.
                And now, all of a sudden, the German umlauts (`Ää, Öö, Üü, ß`) are being displayed incorrectly (something like `Ã¤`) - but only on the files I opened with VS2010.
                
I checked the charset on the site itself and also displaying it with `Response.CharSet` and it was `ISO-8859-1`, which is correct.
                
                So I tried some converting with `notepad++`, but no success.
                I know that setting the charset to `UTF-8` would solve this problem, but a) the charset is set from a database-value and b) it kind of messes things up in other languages.

Comment: I want to add that when I directly edit the file on the server (opening it in notepad++), everything is fine. Is Visual Studio messing some things up in my case?

Comment: Does it work, if you change the charset -in Visual-studio- into utf-8 and you correct the Umlaute, using "Search and Replace"? At least it did help, when I ran into a similar situation in Eclipse.

Comment: open the file in notepad then select save as from the File drop down.  Look at the Encoding selector at the bottom of the drop down.  If ANSI is selected then change it to UTF-8 and save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are displaying a utf-8 encoded file with a iso-8859-1 view. Usually you want to see just one character, but why do you see two instead of one? This is because in utf-8 a german small 'a' letter with 'two dots' is a 2-byte sequence with utf-8 (0xC3 and 0xA4). If this gets NOT displayed as utf-8 but as iso-8859-1 encoding - which means one byte one character - you'll get that what you have mentioned. You'll get the startbyte 0xC3 as a single iso-8859-1 character and the following byte 0xA4 as as a single iso-8859-1 character. In utf-8 this 2-byte sequence must become decoded by extracting the payload bits of the startbyte and the following byte like this:

Startbyte:   11000011
Following:   10100100

So 110 of the startbyte must get stripped off, so 11 is left.
So 10 of the following byte must get stripped off, so 100100 is left.

Chained together this becomes 11100100 which is decimal 228 which should be equal to the german character 'a with two dots' unicode codepoint.

I recommend to let the encoding as it is, utf-8. It is just the encoding of your viewer/editor that should display utf-8 encoded files as utf-8 and not as iso-8859-1. Configure your viewer/editor with utf-8. In other words, configure the viewer's/editor's encoding according to the encoding of the file's content (which is in your case utf-8 and NOT iso-8859-1).

To convert your files or check them for a certain encoding, just use madedit. madedit has a built-in hex-editor which wraps a rectangle around utf-8 sequences, displaying just one character on the right side (the encoded codepoint). It's easy to identify single-byte characters and/or 2/3/4-byte sequences within utf-8 encoded files. It also wraps a rectangle around the 3-byte utf-8 BOM (if any).

Comment: Makes sense; Thanks for explaining this nicely.

Comment: Thanks. Did you examine your file(s) with madedit? It's the only editor i know that doesn't display characters on a 1:1 basis when utf-8 encoded (except single byte chars [ASCII]).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get my hands on that project anymore, so no, I did not examine in yet. Altough I saved your comment, since I sometimes got to work with different charsets (which we all know can be pure hell sometimes :))

Answer (score 1):

Encoding problems have several failure points:

- Check template file encoding
- Check response encoding
- Check database encoding

Check that they are coherent to what you want to output.

Also note that Notepad++ has a "Encode as..." and a "Convert to..."

1st one reads file as encoding specified and 2nd reads file and writes it back to selected encoding (changing file)